# Open Custom Dialog Windows (PyGTK + Quickly)

Tags: application-development, quickly, pygtk, dialog, glade

I have just downloaded Quickly, created a new project, set up simple GUI and created new dialog (*quickly add dialog create* (as you can see, I called it *create*)). I already have click handler in the main window but I don't know how to open my *CreateDialog* from there.

P.S. I am new to PyGTK, Glade and Quickly but I am not new to programming overall.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to get a hold of the dialog gui object. If I remember correctly, quickly uses glade for the gui and then loads it via the GtkBuilder, so. Get the dialog gui object from the builder

`dia = self.builder.get_object('the_name_of_the_dialog_in_glade')`

and then you can run it

`return_value = dia.run()`

the return_value will be a code that corresponds to which button was pressed (which you can change your self in glade) or another code to tell you if the window was destroyed.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 6):

You can also try to have a look at the help for the `add` command. You can do either of these:

- invoke the `quickly help add` command
- invoke the `quickly tutorial` command and browse to the `add` command reference

From the outupt of `quickly help add`

For instance 'quickly add dialog dialog-name' will create:

1. A subclass of `Gtk.Dialog` called `DialogNameDialog` in the module *DialogNameDialog.py*
2. A glade file called *DialogNameDialog.ui* in the *media/ui* directory
3. A catalog file called *dialog_name_dialog.xml* also in the *media/ui* directory

To edit the UI for the dialog, run:
`$ quickly design`

To edit the behavior, run:
`$ quickly edit`

To use the dialog you have to invoke it from another python file:

```
# 1. Import the dialog
import DialogNameDialog

# 2. Create an instance of the dialog
dialog = DialogNameDialog.DialogNameDialog()

# 3. Run the dialog and hide the dialog
result = dialog.run()
dialog.hide()
```

Comment: Note: quickly add dialog <NewName> ,command adds 'Dialog' to the ending of the file, so do like.. <NewName> make a file call NewNameDialog.ui and new_name_dialog.xml to the '/data/ui' folder  ....