# Open Dialog, created with quickly does not work

Tags: python, application-development, quickly

I tried to open a dialog like David Planella describs here (and quickly help add):
[Open Custom Dialog Windows (PyGTK + Quickly)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132624/open-custom-dialog-windows-pygtk-quickly)

But this don't works for me. I always get the same Error-Message if I open the creadted Dialog:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'NewDialogNameDialog'
```

(Note: My Dialog-Name is replaced with "NewDialogNameDialog" to be more general.)
I tried to test a tutorial for the Ubuntu app showdown to learn how to use quickly and python.

I can also add the whole source-code if you wish.

Comment: This error appears when I try to open the dialog on runtime. The line wich causes the error is: "dialog = DialogNameDialog.NewDialogNameDialog()" (terminal-output)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe there is a typo in his example.  The class and the module should have the same name.  So instead of:

```
DialogNameDialog.NewDialogNameDialog()
```

it should likely be:

```
DialogNameDialog.DialogNameDialog()
```

(i.e. drop the New)

If that doesn't work, I'd like to see both files if possible.

Comment: THX very much! If I use DialogNameDialog.DialogNameDialog() it works! That is very confusing: in all the tutorials there is "New" before the Dialog-Name - also in the help of quickly....

Comment: Fixed the code in the answer mentioned, thanks!